# Sending SMS from non default app requires confirmation on Color OS devices. Is there any workaround for this?

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

When I try to send an SMS using [sendMultipartTextMessage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager) function it asks for confirmation on Color OS 5.1 (Realme 2 Pro) as you can see from below screenshot.

[image: Send SMS Confirmation]

Is there any way to avoid this dialog and send SMS directly cause this is not the standard behavior in Stock Android?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @himCream I think if you can set your application as default SMS app then this can be avoided.

Comment: How to make app default SMS app? Have you tried it?

Comment: You can follow the blog post from [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) so the user can set it as the default app. My app can't be default app cause It will provide the negative user experience.

Comment: So I didn't try it but you can install an app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moez.QKSMS) and make it default to try it out. If it doesn't raise the dialog like that when sending a message then it should work for your app too.